# Removing column_names in a hash result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I wanted to remove id and abc_id, created_At and updated_at while iterating through tablename.attributes. This is the fix I could come up with. Any other best fix I could use. Thanks

```
chash = tablename.attributes // outputs hash of key and value
list = ["A", "B", "created_at", "updated_at"]
list.each do |l|
   chash = chash.tap {|c| c.delete(l)}
 end
```

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except

Answer (score 1):

You can use [delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if) method.

```
chash.delete_if {|k,_| list.include? k}
```

or [reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-reject) method

```
chash.reject {|k,_| list.include? k}
```

or [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-select) method

```
chash.select {|k,_| !list.include? k}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails, you can use the [`except`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except) method:

```
chash.except!(*list)
```